# How can I allow users from one trusted domain access shared files from another trusted domain?

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008-r2

How can I allow users from one trusted windows 2008 R2 domain access shared files located on another trusted Win2012 domain
without prompting for authentication, is this even possible?

Comment: Share files by SFTP.

Comment: This is exactly what AD Domains & Trusts is for. What is a “trusted” domain to you? To me, it means you setup a [trust](https://blogs.msmvps.com/acefekay/tag/active-directory-trusts/) between the two domains and are able to authenticate to resources in one domain using accounts in the other domain.

Comment: In theory what you said is correct but is not working for me, I was hoping for a clue or troubleshooting hints